# Google Maps Store Locator - PHP/MySQL error with SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, google-maps

I keep getting the error below after submitting my sql statement

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-1 HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20' at line 5

My csv is loaded fine, my sql statement is below :

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM test1-1 
HAVING distance < 25 
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Not sure why this is happening, I changed `markers` to `test1-1` after `FROM` (my table name). I'm new at this, pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is caused by the `-` in `test1-1`.

Simply wrap the table name in backtics:

```
...
FROM `test1-1` 
....
```